# I need to replace a whole sentence with a brand new sentence in an access query in design view

Tags: ms-access-2013

Using MS Access 2016 and trying to run a query. I am using the design view not SQL view

I need to replace a whole sentence with a brand new sentence in an access query in design view.

Example:
I need to replace the words "Not Assigned" with "Manual Input".

I have tried to do replace function but every time I try it and run my query it deletes all my data in the datasheet view.  When I say all data, I mean all columns are deleted and it returns nothing.

Comment: we can't help with design view, since that's graphical. switch to sql view and show us the query it's built for you.

Comment: Are you designing a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` query?

Comment: Is "Not Assigned" the entire value of a field, or are those words just part of the value in the field?